# Vuejs created and mounted doesn't work properly even if at the same level than methods

Tags: vue.js

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with `created()` and `mounted()` in Vue.js. I need to set 2 lists in `created()` - so it means those 2 lists will help me to create a third list which is a merge.

Here is the code :

```
// return data

created () {
    this.retrieveSellOffers();
    this.getAllProducts();
  },
  mounted () {
    this.mergeSellOffersProducts();
  },

  methods: {
    retrieveSellOffers() {
      this.sellerId = localStorage.sellerId;
      SellOfferServices.getAllBySellerId(this.sellerId)
        .then((response) => {
          this.sellOffers = response.data;
          console.log("this.sellOffers");
          console.log(this.sellOffers);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    getAllProducts() {
      ProductServices.getAll()
        .then((response) => {
          this.products = response.data;
          console.log("this.products");
          console.log(this.products);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
      });
    },
    mergeSellOffersProducts () {
      console.log(this.products) // print empty array
      console.log(this.sellOffers) // print empty array
      for (var i = 0; i < this.sellOffers.length; i++) {
          if (this.sellOffers[i].productId === this.products[i]._id) {
            this.arr3.push({id: this.sellOffers[i]._id, price: this.sellOffers[i].price, description: this.products[i].description});
        }
      }
      this.arr3 = this.sellOffers;
    },
}

//end of code
```

So my problem is when I enter in `mergeSellOffersProducts()`, my 2 lists are empty arrays :/

EDIT :

This way worked for me :

```
 async mounted() {
    await this.retrieveSellOffers();
    await this.getAllProducts();
    this.mergeSellOffersProducts();
  },
methods: {
    async retrieveSellOffers() {
      this.sellerId = localStorage.sellerId;
      this.sellOffers = (await axios.get('link/api/selloffer/seller/', { params: { sellerId: this.sellerId } })).data;
    },
    async getAllProducts() {
      this.products = (await axios.get('link/api/product')).data;
    },
}
```

Comment: It's the expected behaviour because that you have asynchronous operations in lifecycle methods is up to you and doesn't affect Vue in any way. What is the reasoning behind created/mounted separation? It doesn't make sense for asynchronous operations as well.

Comment: Well, I have my two lists : sellOffers and products, I want to simply merge them when I land on the page. sellOffers contains the id of the product. And I want to print them in the same table, with sell offer datas associated to the product.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to merge the 2 lists, they aren't filled up yet. You need to await the calls.

```
async created () {
  await this.retrieveSellOffers();
  await this.getAllProducts();
},
async mounted () {
  await this.mergeSellOffersProducts();
},
```

Comment: If you write an answer that can appear to be a clarifying question, you risk it being downvoted and flagged as Not an Answer and deleted. It would be much clearer if you could rephrase it as a statement rather than a question, and even clearer if you demonstrated your answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the reason is: Vue **does not wait** for the promises to resolve before continuing with the component lifecycle.
- Your functions **retrieveSellOffers()** and **getAllProducts()** contain Promise so maybe you have to await them in the **created()** hook:

```
async created: {
  await this.retrieveSellOffers();
  await this.getAllProducts();
}
```

Comment: I think this way of writing created doesn't work, I tried but I get errors...

Comment: @Stormy It can work only if you written methods like that, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448381/3731501 because you didn't return promises in original code. If you have errors, consider updating the question with them.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a bunch of asynchronous methods and don't properly wait for them to finish, that's why your data is not set in `mounted`. Since Vue does not `await` its lifecycle hooks, you have to deal with the synchronization yourself.

One Vue-ish way to fix it be to replace your method `mergeSellOffersProducts` with a computed prop (eg `mergedSellOffersProducts`). Instead of generating `arr3` it would simply return the merged array. It will be automatically updated when `products` or `sellOffers` is changed. You would simply use `mergedSellOffersProducts` in your template, instead of your current `arr3`.

If you only want to update the merged list when *both* API calls have completed, you can either manually sync them with `Promise.all`, or you could handle this case in the computed prop and return `[]` if either of the arrays is not set yet.

Answer (score -1):

So I tried to async my 2 methods :

```
    async retrieveSellOffers() {
      this.sellerId = localStorage.sellerId;
      this.sellOffers = (await axios.get('linkhidden/api/selloffer/', { params: { sellerId: '615b1575fde0190ad80c3410' } })).data;
      console.log("this.sellOffers")
      console.log(this.sellOffers)
    },
    async getAllProducts() {
      this.products = (await axios.get('linkhidden/api/product')).data;
      console.log("this.products")
      console.log(this.products)
    },
    mergeSellOffersProducts () {
      console.log("here")
      console.log(this.sellOffers)
      console.log(this.products)
      this.arr3 = this.sellOffers;
    },
```

My data are well retrieved, but yet when I enter in created, the two lists are empty...

Comment: This is not an answer, consider adding this code to the question instead.

Comment: Please follow @EstusFlask indication